# ReQL Updating object inside an embedded array emits "create" and "delete" events when listening to changes

Tags: rethinkdb, reql, database, nosql

I am hitting the following problem: Suppose that I have the following structure:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
       "arr": [{"text":"item1"}]
    }
}
```

And the following query:

```
r.db('test').table('test').get(1).update(function (item) {
    return {
        data: {
          arr: item('data')('arr').map(function (row) {
             return r.branch(
                  row('text').eq('item1'),
                  row.merge({updated:true}),
                  row
             )
          })
        }
    }
})
```

I am listening for changes in this specific array only, and when the item is updated both create and delete events are emitted. I really need to receive an update event, e.g. old_val is not null and new_val is not null.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, I decided to drop the embedded array and use table joins, this avoids all possible hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
r.db('test').table('test')('data')('arr').changes()
  .filter(function(doc) {
    return doc('new_val').ne(null).and(doc('old_val').ne(null))
  })
```

I'll only show update to array. If you need to get access to other document field, try this:

```
r.db('test').table('test').changes()
  .filter(function(doc) {
    return doc('new_val')('data')('arr').ne(null).and(doc('old_val')('data')('arr').ne(null))
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a scalable solution, check out my answer.